# Siri Shortcuts App always throw kCLErorrdomain error 2 in geolocater

Tags: geolocation, sirishortcuts

I have a very strange erorr if i want geolocate an adress with Siri Shortcuts App. 
IN WIFI it works - in cellular mode not.

Anyone else with the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Stupid error. 
Mobile data was Disabled in cellular Mode